# Trying to get json from get request http authenticated

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm trying to get some data from an api that is protected by http authentication.
I'm want the response to be a json, but I'm getting a string innstead.
What can I do to fix this?

This is my code:

```
//init curl
$ch = curl_init();
$process = curl_init($url."?".$queryString);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', ''));
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '');
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$return = curl_exec($process);
print_r($return);
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what is returned

Comment: Are you getting a JSON String by any chance?

Comment: I am fairly sure that using `curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', ''));` is telling the server YOU ARE PASSING JSON and NOT that you want JSON back!